# Usage of Repartition in Spark SQL Queries

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark-SQL. I read somewhere about using `REPARTITION()` before Joins in SparkSQL queries to achieve better performance.

However, I use **plain** Spark SQL queries (**not** PySparkSQL) and I am struggling to find out the **equivalent usage syntax** of `REPARTITION` in such plain queries like the sample shown below.

```
/* how to use repartition() here ? */
select t1.id, t2.name
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
on t1.id = t2.id;
```

Can anyone please share the usage and syntax to be used in the above sample query ? Also, I want to understand in which scenarios should repartition be used for achieving better join performance.

Thanks.

Comment: To see in which situations is using repartition useful, you may check my recent article https://towardsdatascience.com/should-i-repartition-836f7842298c related to this subject.

Answer (score 0):

As per **[spark-24940](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24940)** From **`Spark-2.4`** you can use **`repartition,coalesce`** hints in sql.

---

**`Example:`**

```
#sample dataframe has 12 partitions
spark.sql(" select * from tmp").rdd.getNumPartitions()
12

#after repartition has 5 partitions
spark.sql(" select /*+ REPARTITION(5) */ * from tmp").rdd.getNumPartitions()
5
```

Comment: thanks Shu.. In which scenarios should we use the repartition or coalesce to improve join/query performance ? any example please ?